# How to render HTML tag to php using fpdf

Tags: php, html, fpdf

How to render html on my FPDF file? the content always showing strings with HTML tags for example if I input like this

[image: View picture for sample]

the output will be like this

[image: view picture for sample]

I tried *strip_tags()* like below to output the content without tags but the HTML shows no effect/rendering.

```
strip_tags($item['output'])
```

What can you suggest me to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use  `WriteHTML()` method.

See http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script42.php